# Is there a way in Python to display two images side by side in scale using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to display two images side by side in scale. This is the code:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 15))
ax1.imshow(bird_rescaled)
ax2.imshow(bird_resized)
```

Unfortunately I just managed to come to this result:

[image: different sized images of a bird].

 What I'd like to have is two in-scale images side by side, kind of like this:

[image: beautiful collage]

Is there some function argument I'm missing that could solve this?

Comment: try to add the `sharey=True` parameter in `plt.subplots`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway), `sharey=True` helped solving this problem.

 I modified the code in this way:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, sharex=True, figsize=(12, 6))
ax1.imshow(bird_rescaled)
ax2.imshow(bird_resized)
```

adding `sharex=True`
so that now the result looks perfect. [I can't post images because I don't have at least 10 reputation :(]

I also changed the values passed to the `figsize` argument:

 I wanted the images to be 6x6 so the total figure needed to be 12x6.